# How to get attribute label in Yii2 ActiveRecord

Tags: activerecord, yii2

How to get attribute label in Yii2?

I found this function `getAttributeLabel()` [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#getAttributeLabel%28%29-detail) in Yii2 doc, I am using it in a controller. But it's throwing an error:

`Call to undefined function app\controllers\getAttributeLabel()`

Comment: do u want to see all attributes labels of a model?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
$model          =   new ModelName();
print_r($model->attributeLabels());
```

if you use the above code you can get an array containing all attribute labels of a model

Answer (score 20):

```
$task = new Task();

//to get single attribute label
$label = $task->getAttributeLabel('task_title');

//to get all attribute label
$labels = $task->attributeLabels();
```

Answer (score 8):

Since Yii 2.0.13 `ActiveRecord` implements [`StaticInstanceInterface`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-staticinstanceinterface), so you can use [`instance()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-staticinstanceinterface#instance()-detail) to get static instance of model. Using it should be cleaner and more efficient that manually creating instance of model to use its non-static methods.

```
$singleLabel = MyModel::instance()->getAttributeLabel('my_attribute');

$allLabels = MyModel::instance()->attributeLabels();
```